# I am unable to connect aws emr using ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I have already created a EMR cluster in my AWS console. Then i got my private key file from them. In putty configuration i added that key file in to this path **Connection -> SSH -> Auth**. Also i changed the security group configuration like as below link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-gs-ssh.html. But i am still getting same error.
For further description i have attached some screen shots. Can any one support to solve this issue?

[image: private key file]

[image: host details]

[image: timeout error]

Comment: A timeout suggests there is a problem with the security group setup.

Comment: Can you post the security group inbound and outbound in your question?

Comment: I found the root cause of that issue. When i tried to login using putty with previous host details of my cluster. But At that time it went to the terminated status. Then i created new cluster and tried to login using new host details. It worked fine.

Comment: Do not modify the default security group as the post suggest. Create a security group for inbound ssh and add it to the EMR's additional security group.